# PHP query: adding multiple fields in an array?

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I combine these two fields (category name and posts per page) into one line of code?

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'investor-news' ) );?>
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );?>
```

Comment: `<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'investor-news' ,'posts_per_page' => 5) ); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Manual:-https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

You can do it like below:-

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'investor-news',
    'posts_per_page' =>  5
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use something like this:

```
query_posts(array('category_name' => 'investor-news', 'posts_per_page' => 5));

while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    //display post code here
endwhile; wp_reset_query();
```